# Update Users Personal Settings on Sharepoint with Custom Trusted Login Provider

Tags: claims-based-auth, claims, claim-provider

Am not able to see the logged in user's email address in the Personal Settings.
I have configured Custom STS Provider on Sharepoint.
I also have a claim type mapping like below.

Can any one please let me know what could be the problem?

```
$tp = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer
$tp.ClaimTypeInformation
...
DisplayName                    : EmailAddress
InputClaimType                 : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity
                                 /claims/emailaddress
MappedClaimType                : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity
                                 /claims/emailaddress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claims included in your token are only used to make authorization decisions inside of SharePoint. The custom claims provider provides claims augmentation (adding claims to your token) and claims lookup (people picker functionality).

If you want to have user properties in the user profile service application, you still have to configure an import connection to Active Directory or the LDAP directory your users are coming from.

SharePoint maps the correct user profile to the authenticated user by means of the SPS-ClaimID attribute.

A nice article on how this works can be found [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/08/08/mapping-user-profiles-for-saml-users-with-an-ad-import-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx). It's about SharePoint 2013 and Active Directory, but it works the same for SharePoint 2010 and/or SAML claims.

Comment: I was seeing trying to implement this solution before also. But unfortunately User Profile Syncronization service is not available on Sharpoint Foundation.
Thanks for your answer :)
Do you have/know a solution for this issue in Sharepoint Foundation?